# Upgrading Sharepoint 3.0 to SQL 2005 Backend?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sharepoint, sql-server-2000

We're trying to get rid of all of our SQL Server 2000 databases to re purpose our old DB server... Sharepoint 3.0 is being a showstopper.

I've looked at a lot of guides from Microsoft and tried the instructions in those. I've also just tried the good ol' exec sp_detach_db / sp_attach_db with no luck. Has anyone actually done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my boss has. it was a real pain. permissions issues. he used the built in sharepoint backup tool. I can more details tomorrow if need. I'll check back.

I'm back. Here's the steps he used.

- install an instance of sql server
  2005 on the sql 2000 box
  (side-by-side)
- back up the sharepoint site using the sharepoint admin tools. This will create a one mother of a large xml file w/ the whole kit and kaboodle (the site & all it's content)
- delete the old-n-busted sharepoint site
- create a new hotness sharepoint site using the sql server 2005 as the database.
- do a restore from the xml backup using the admin tools  - this will take hours to run (thank you xml ...)
- Bingo!
- P.S. I forgot, the account you use to do the restore must be an 'sa' account.

Comment: I'll give this a try and keep Stackoverflow up to date.